# Integral over X as supremum of integrals over finite subsets of X.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to prove that
$$\int f d\mu = \sup \left\lbrace \int_E f d \mu, E \in S, \mu(E)< \infty \right\rbrace,$$
given that $\int f d\mu < \infty$. $f$ is a positive measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $S$ is $X$'s $\sigma$-algebra.

Attempt:
Since for all $E \in S$, it is true that $E \subset X$, then we get $f\chi_E\le f$, from which $$\int_E f \le \int f .$$

It follows that: $$\sup \left\lbrace \int_E f d \mu, E \in S, \mu(E)< \infty \right\rbrace \le \int f d\mu.$$

I want to show that:
$$\int f d\mu \le \sup \left\lbrace \int_E f d \mu, E \in S, \mu(E)< \infty \right\rbrace.$$

By exhibiting $E\in S$ satisfying: $\mu(E)<\infty,$ such that $\int f \le \int_E f$, as I would then have both inequatities, proving the equality.

I am having trouble trying to use the hypothesis: $\int f d\mu < \infty$. I tried constructing a sequence of functions $f_n$ whose limit-inferior was $f$ in order to apply Fatou's lemma, but I don't know if $\mu(X)<\infty,$ so this approach lead me nowhere.

Anyone got any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work directly from the definition.

Since $f$ is integrable, we have a sequence $s_n$ of simple measurable functions such that $0 \le s_n \le f$ and $\int s_n \to \int f$.

Each $s_n$ has the form $s_n = \sum \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$, where $\alpha_k > 0$ and the$A_k$ are measurable, $\mu A_k < \infty$ and, without loss of generality, disjoint. Let $E_n = \cup A_k$. Then $\mu E_n < \infty$. Then we have $s_n \le f \cdot1_{E_n}$, and hence $\int s_n \le \int f \cdot1_{E_n} = \int_{E_n} f \le \int f$. The result follows, since $\int s_n \to \int f$.

(**Note**: The fact that $\mu A_k < \infty$ follows from $\int s_n = \sum_k \alpha_k \mu A_k \le \int f < \infty$, and $\alpha_k >0$.)

**Addendum**: We have $\sup \{ \int_E f | \mu E < \infty \} \ge \int_{E_n} f$. Since $\int_{E_n} f \to \int f$, we have $\sup \{ \int_E f | \mu E < \infty \} \ge \int f$, as required.

Comment: I am not sure if I'm following you here. I got $\int s_n \le \int f \cdot 1_{E_n} \le \int f$. I want to show that there exists $\mu$-finite $E$ such that $int f \le \int_E f$, the problem is, I don't know what happens to the middle term of your inequality when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I am using the definition of the integral in terms of simple functions to show the existence of some $E_n$ such that $\int_{E_n} f = \int f \cdot 1_{E_n} \to \int f$. That was the problem, right?

Comment: You showed that there is a sequence $\int_{E_n}f$ converging to $\int f$. I now need to translate this into a condition on the supremum of all the $\int_E f$.

Comment: You have  $\sup \{ \int_E f | \mu E < \infty \} \ge \lim_n \int_{E_n} f = \int f$.

Comment: You can't, in general, show that there is a $\mu$-finite $E$ such that $\int f \le \int_E f$. You can show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\mu$-finite $E$ such that $\int f -\epsilon < \int_E f$. For example, take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$ on $[1,\infty)$ with the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Yes, I completely missed that inequality. This does indeed complete the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$E_n= \{x\in X\ | \frac1{n-1} \geq f(x)>\frac1{n} \}$$ with $\frac10=\infty$

Clearly $\mu (E_n)$ is finite or else $\int fd\mu=\infty$, and $$\int fd\mu=\int_{\cup E_n} fd\mu= \sum_n \int_{E_n} fd\mu < \infty$$

The series of positive real numbers converge, then the tail must go to zero. So, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $M$ such that $$\int fd\mu< \sum_{n=1}^{M} \int_{E_n} fd\mu+\epsilon=\int_{\cup_{n=1}^ME_n}fd\mu+\epsilon$$

So $\sup \{ \int_E fd\mu\  |\ \mu (E) < \infty \} \ge \int fd\mu$, and the other inequality is trivial.

Comment: You need to justify the exchange of integration and summation. You might as well use $E_n = f^{-1} [\frac{1}{n},\infty)$. But you still need to involve some convergence theorem.

Comment: This is already too complete of a solution . Many books prove (in one line) the fact that integral of a sum (of positive measurable functions) is the sum of the integrals.

Comment: If you are willing to use the monotone convergence theorem, the answer follows immediately from the fact that $f_n = f \cdot 1_{f^{-1}[\frac{1}{n}, \infty)}$ is a pointwise non-decreasing sequence of functions that converges to $f$ at each $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late sorry, but this can also help to new people:

We can combine both answers from **cooper** and **PVAL** as follows:

Observe that $(E_n) \subset S$ defined as $E_n = f^{-1} [\frac{1}{n}, \infty)$, is monotone increasing. So, it induces a sequence $(f_n) \subset M^+(X, S)$ defined as $f_n = f \cdot 1_{E_n}$ such that $(f_n)$ is monotone increasing and $f_n \to f$ as $n \to \infty$ (because $E_n \to X$).

If $\mu(E_n) = \infty$, $\int f d\mu = \infty$. Thus,
$$\int f_n d\mu = \int_{E_n} f d\mu \in \Big\{\int_E f d\mu: E \in S, \mu(E) < + \infty\Big\}, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

By the M.C.T.,

$$\int_{E} f d\mu = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} f_n d\mu, \quad \forall E \in S$$

In particular, for $X \in S$,

$$\sup\Big\{\int_E f d\mu: E \in S, \mu(E) < + \infty\Big\} \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X} f_n d\mu = \int f d\mu$$

which is the other inequality. The first one, as **alonso** wrote, is correctly observed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{E_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $S$ with $\mu(E_j)<\infty$ such that

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{E_j}f~\mathrm{d}\mu=\sup_{\substack{E\in S\\ \mu(E)<\infty}}\int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu.$$

Me may assume without loss of generality that $f(x)>0$ for $\mu$-almost every $x\in E_j$ for each $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider now the increasing (by inclusion) sequence of sets $\{F_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by

$$F_j=\bigcup_{i=0}^j E_i.$$

Then clearly

$$\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{F_j}f~\mathrm{d}\mu=\sup_{\substack{E\in S\\ \mu(E)<\infty}}\int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu$$

(we can squeeze the limit between the two sides in the first equality). If we can show that

$$\mu\left(X\setminus\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}E_j\right)=0,$$

then by the monotone convergence theorem that

$$\sup_{\substack{E\in S\\ \mu(E)<\infty}}\int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{F_j}f~\mathrm{d}\mu=\int_Xf~\mathrm{d}\mu,$$

and we get the result. We thus show this. So suppose this is not the case. Without loss of generality suppose

$$0<\mu\left(X\setminus\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}E_j\right)<\infty.$$

Set

$$\Omega=X\setminus\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}E_j$$

and observe that

$$\sup_{\substack{E\in S\\ \mu(E)<\infty}}\int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu<\sup_{\substack{E\in S\\ \mu(E)<\infty}}\int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_{\Omega}f~\mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_{j\to\infty}\int_{F_j\cup\Omega}f~\mathbb{d}\mu\leq \sup_{\substack{E\in S\\ \mu(E)<\infty}}\int_E f~\mathrm{d}\mu,$$

which is a contradiction. The result follows.